# Disable a next/previous button(link) temporarily when clicked in jQuery Cycle plugin (not necessarily a jquery cycle issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I need to prevent link from being clicked for let's say 2 seconds.

Here is an example http://jsbin.com/orinib/4/edit

When you look at the rendered mode you see next and prev links. When you click next, it slides with a nice transition. However if you click multiple times there is no transition sort of, which is expected. But my question: is this how can I prevent clicking on the next link, for about 2 seconds (or what ever time it takes for transition to happen) so that no matter what transition will occur.
This is what I tried to use, but did not work:

```
function(){
var thePreventer = false;
$("#next").bind($(this),function(e){
    if(!thePreventer){
        thePreventer = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            thePreventer = false;
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

}

Which I got from here ["Disable" a link temporarily when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380722/disable-a-link-temporarily-when-clicked) I think. I believe that i cannot achieve this effect with this code (although it works on other links). I believe this is due to the fact that cycle-plugin got a hold of that link, and I understand that I have to bind/tap-into this functionality of the plugin. Please note: that this code may not work I just used it to show that I tried it and it did not work, you can reuse it if you have to or give me your own stuff.

Please help, if you can.

**EDIT**:
As **mrtsherman** proposed this simple yet elegant **ANSWER**: http://jsfiddle.net/LCWLb.

Comment: I don't really see how the cycle plugin fits into here; you don't have any code related to it in this example.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that this (code) is what I tried and it did not work. I fixed it with the new edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [cycle options page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html). There are a number of ways to do this. I would consider using the pager event onPrevNextEvent. You can assign a callback function.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    pager:  '#nav', 
    onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement)  { 
        //disable controls
    },
    after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
        //reenable controls
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually tried both onPrevNextEvent and after but was not able to make it work, but i'll give it another try, since you seem to point me into right direction.

Comment: Here is a ghetto mockup - i just hide the controls using the events. http://jsbin.com/orinib/6/edit

Comment: Hahaha, it's unbelievable what kind of unexpected (outside the box) solution people can propose. I will defiantly look into this solution.

Comment: I was more comfortable working in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LCWLb/. Create a blocking element and then hide/show it to prevent the links from being clicked.

Comment: Yes, yes oh god yes! I'll implement this solution and will mark your answer as correct. Sorry about jsbin, I usually use both jsbin and jsfiddle in my questions so that people can be comfortable with what they are accustomed to.

Comment: Thank you mrtsherman, for the answer. Thanks to you I now know how to use this functionality (onPrevNextEvent: and after:). And I do use this plugin often.

Answer (score 0):

The following will temporarily prevent clicks while a slideshow is running, [as shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/8PKDD/4/):

```
$.fn.extend({
    delayClick: function(callback) {
        this.bind('click', function(e) {
            $self = $(this);
            if( $self.hasClass('disabled') ) {
               $('#log').append('<p>click prevented on '+$self.attr('id')+'</p>');
            } 
            else {
               $self.addClass('disabled');
               callback.call(this, [arguments]);
               setTimeout(function() {
                   $self.removeClass('disabled');
               }, 1000);
            }
            return false; 
        });
    } 
});
```