# jQuery Cycle - Stop cycling multiple slides at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

So I have a custom transition which animates various elements at a time.  When the user clicks the next slide button quickly (before the animation is finished) it causes all sorts of problems.  How do I solve this?  I tried a nooby idea of adding/removing the active class on the links but that didn't work.

Here is a jfiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SHRA6/12/

Here is my js:

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.slideCustom = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    $caption = $('.serverbig')
    $feature = $('.featurehol')
    $heading = $('h2')
    opts.fxFn = function(curr,next,opts,cb,fwd) {
        $feature.animate({ top: '350px' }, 500, opts.easing);
        $heading.animate({ left: '-550px' }, 500, opts.easing);
        $caption.animate({ right: '-550px' }, 500, opts.easing,  function() {
            $(curr).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, opts.easing, function() {
            });         
            $(next).css({ display: 'block'}).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, opts.easing);
            $feature.animate({ top: '66px' }, 500, opts.easing);
            $heading.animate({ left: '0' }, 500, opts.easing);
            $caption.animate({ right: '0px' }, 500, opts.easing, function() {
            if(cb) cb();
            });
        });
    }
}
 $('#sliderb').cycle({ 
    fx:     'slideCustom', 
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '.nextslide', 
    prev:   '.prevslide',
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
    slideExpr: '.slide',
});
```

An additional problem causes the background (main slide) to flash in, instead of fading in using the opacity animation.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you make a live example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also, please include well formatted code in your questions.

Comment: I added a jfiddle to post.

Comment: Pressing the Next button doesn't seem do be doing anything in the fiddle

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @RickCigarette

Comment: I added the resource http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.cycle/2.99/jquery.cycle.all.js

Comment: Maybe that isn't added for everyone?  I've never used fiddle before.  EDIT:  I also just changed the link, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before animate like so `$feature.stop().animate(/* your code */)` etc.

If you actually wanna disable the controls you will have to hook into `onPrevNextEvent:`.
There's an elegant solution in another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001490/disable-a-next-previous-buttonlink-temporarily-when-clicked-in-jquery-cycle-pl).

They use a transparent block element on top of the controls to disable them while the event is in progress. Checkout the last edit and fiddle in the question.

EDIT: You were experiencing strange behaviour due to this line

```
 $caption.animate({ right: '0px' }, 500, opts.easing, function() {
            if(cb) cb();
 });
```

Take the callback check and put it right after this animation call.

Comment: Yes that works, although I would prefer for it not to interrupt the current animation.

Comment: What exactly are the "problems" though?

Comment: Hopefully the jfiddle should be working now.  The background color basically changes a few times and then very choppily the content for the correct slide is animated in.

Comment: Do you want to disable the link for the time of animation?

Comment: Yes that was my original idea but the way I tried didn't seem to work.

Comment: Found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001490/disable-a-next-previous-buttonlink-temporarily-when-clicked-in-jquery-cycle-pl

Comment: Hmmn, that is similar to what I tried.  But if you click very quickly for a while it breaks that for some reason (to do with the 2 stages of animation I think) http://jsfiddle.net/SHRA6/24/

Comment: It seems like the cb() function inside the last animation callback was messing things up! Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/SHRA6/29/

Comment: Nice!  I actually stuck with the stop method because it means you can skip a couple slides really quickly if you want.  This above method is probably best in most cases though.